# Are there special steps I should take to install the apostrophe-cms museum demo project?

Tags: installation, apostrophe-cms

I'm a Mac user, new to Apostrophe CMS, and to node.js and even to the Terminal app. I have successfully installed the basic project as described in the developer documentation. Having done so, I then realised that there is the option to install the Open Museum project that is used for the Apostrophe demo site. This has not gone well.

I got lots of alarming messages in the Terminal window, and the installed site does not work - I just get a skeletal home page with no working links.

I have saved the Terminal window text, but before posting all of that I thought I would ask if there are special steps to take in this case, and whether the Open Museum project  is up to date - several of the messages refer to things that are deprecated. I didn't get any of that with the basic project installation.

All suggestions gratefully received.

cheers

Chris

Comment: If you're going to refer to "alarming messages," please include those messages here so they can be used in diagnosis.

Comment: As I said in the original post: "I have saved the Terminal window text, but before posting all of that I thought I would ask if there are special steps to take in this case, and whether the Open Museum project is up to date." Looks like I'm not allowed to post such a lot of stuff in a comment, so I guess I should make a new post?

Comment: Right on. They're probably unrelated. Since you're already in there, it might be easier to share those in the Discord if they aren't blocking you but are confusing. If they are blocking you, then another SO question might be appropriate if you can't find a related question already in here.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the response to your [duplicate question in the Apostrophe Discord chat](https://discordapp.com/channels/517772094482677790/517782236800745495/731821563879620619), the "empty" page is because you hadn't added any content yet. A boilerplate codebase, whether [apostrophe-boilerplate](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-boilerplate/), [Open Museum](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-open-museum), or any other, only brings with it the application code, not any uploaded files or database.

Comment: Thanks Alex. As noted in that Discord exchange, I think the wording of the developer docs is slightly misleading about the Open Museum download.

Comment: Absolutely. I have an update in the works to help with that. Thanks for raising the issue! https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-documentation/pull/294